# Reportico : yii2 How to embed Links?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, reportico

I have created a Reportico Project named "atom" and a Report called "Receipts"  and then I created action=receipts in ReportController. [This](http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/embedding-reports-prepare-bare) is the tutorial I followed:

Controller code  :

```
public function actionReceipts()
{
  return $this->render('receipts');
}
```

I created receipts.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Reports');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="report-index">



<div class="container">
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-1">
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">


     <?php 
       $reportico = \Yii::$app->getModule('reportico');
    $engine = $reportico->getReporticoEngine();        // Fetches reportico engine
    $engine->access_mode = "ONEREPORT";                // Allows access to single specified report
    $engine->initial_execute_mode = "PREPARE";         // Starts user in report criteria selection mode
    $engine->initial_project = "atom";            // Name of report project folder
    $engine->initial_report = "receipts";           // Name of report to run
    $engine->bootstrap_styles = "3";                   // Set to "3" for bootstrap v3, "2" for V2 or false for no bootstrap
    $engine->force_reportico_mini_maintains = true;    // Often required
    $engine->bootstrap_preloaded = true;               // true if you dont need Reportico to load its own bootstrap
    $engine->clear_reportico_session = true;           // Normally required
    $engine->execute();  
    ?>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

my code should open

```
http://localhost/Atom/backend/web/index.php?r=report%2Freceipts
```

when i try it i got like the pic i attached

[image]

when i type the password that in config.php  `define('SW_ADMIN_PASSWORD','1234');` nothing showing .

i don't need to force user to type a password !

and i need to embed the report in  Criteria Entry Mode .
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly if you dont want to prompt for a password, then take out the password from the config.php file or use the project configuration option to blank it.If you want to keep it then add into the code (before the execute call)

`$engine->initial_project_password = "1234";`

Secondly i think this wont help as you are seeing blank... can you try one of the above options to get rid of the password prompt and then see if it works. If you still get blanks then we need to investigate the ajax calls. Are yo unable to go into your web browser debug network tab and on pressing something, note the link sent to server and see response?

Comment: i remove it from config.php and still i got blank page ! and still asking for password .

Comment: by the way when I open 'http://localhost/Atom/backend/web/index.php?r=reportico' the password disappeared.  It's open the dashboard without password.

Comment: I got the solution : it was in Configure Project .. i forgot  to add Host name. Or IP .

Answer (score 0):

You could use the url helper

```
use yii\helpers\Url;


echo '<a href="' . Url:to(['/report/receipts']) . 
               '" type="button" class="btn  btn-block btn-default">Receipts</a>';
```

could be you should set the action related

```
 $engine->initial_report = Url:to(['/report/receipts']);        // Name of report to run
```

Comment: yeah i did and the link works fine .. but the page not work perfectly .. the report i created work but with link its not working .. i'll add more pic.

Comment: please explain better your comment  .. what do you mean with "he report i created work but with link its not working ."  update the question with the related  code and proper info

Comment: After install Repotico there is something like dashboard you can create a projects and reports and you can test them i created a project and report and i test it and its work in dashboard ..  after that there is embedding report that's what i did .. then there is embedding links to report this is my problem i got nothing.

Comment: If you can post the related  code (not only the simpe link ) i could take a look

Comment: I have update the asnwer  with a brief  suggestion .. hope is useful ..

Comment: No it doesn't Nothing changes and i changed your code to work from `Url:to(['/report/receipts']);`  to  `Url::toRoute(['/report/receipts']);`   but i got the same problem nothing shows like the first pic .